# blynk for python3

Tags: software-installation, python-3

I run this command to try to install Blynk for python on my raspberry pi. I want it to get it working for python3 but when I tell python to "import BlynkLib" it can't find the module. Can someone here give me the correct command to install Blynk for python3.

This is the command I tried:

'''sudo pip install blynklib'''

Comment: Just to let you know I can't find any tutorials that tell me how to do this.

Comment: Usually only "sudo pip3 ..." installs python 3 stuff. So perhaps you can try "pip3".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to "tlfongo1" I got it to work. The answer is: Use pip3 instead of pip.